# Categorical Data Analysis or ML methods?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, references

What is the difference between classical categorical data analysis (as taught by e.g. Agresti's book Categorical Data Analysis) and the classification-related methods from ML (as taught by e.g. The Elements of Statistical Learning: SVM, Bayesian classifiers, etc )?

Based on what little I know, they both seem to deal with statistical regression-like problems where $Y$ is categorical, so what are the differences in the methods taught and their applications?

Somebody told me that the ML-approach is the modern approach that everybody is using these days, and the Agresti-book is outdated, theoretical stuff that I shouldn't bother with. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

In my field (sociology) Machine Learning techniques are very very very rare, and the techniques from Agressti's book are dominant, and I don't expect that to change. I don't think one is replacing the other, they are different tools for different problems. Roughly speaking Machine Learning is good when you want to predict, categorical data analysis is good when you want to explain. My field is much more interested in explaining.

In specific fields there is a lot of enthusiasm about Machine Learning, but at the risk of sounding old: we have seen such phases before. (anybody remember fractals and chaos theory) The good thing about such a phase is that a lot of work on that specific topic gets done. However, the enthusiasm will eventually die down when it becomes clear that the results will be nowhere near is world changing as initially prophesied. After that the topic will find it's own niche, and be useful in that niche.

Comment: ML is a “niche” used in “specific fields”? It’s already used all over the place - the most obvious example being every time you go online you’re interacting with ML algorithms. I’d recommend reading “The Master Algorithm” for a more - up to date - perspective on ML. It may not end up being the cure all some claim, but it’s already an enormously useful tool in many many areas and likely will make its way into your field. Without being rude, when CDA started to make its way into your field, I’m sure there were people talking about it like you are taking about ML right now.

Comment: "when CDA started to make its way into your field, I’m sure there were people talking about it like you are taking about ML right now" That is incorrect. I wasn't there myself, but I have talked to many people who were there, and they reported a ready acceptance of these techniques, and I find that plausible. My sub-field is very methodologically interested. One could legitimately argue too much so, as it takes too much time away from the actual substance. However, the new method has to add something to our understanding of the problem, and ML just isn't made for that.

Comment: This isn't a critique of ML, just as it isn't a critique of a hammer that it is awful at dealing with screws.

Comment: I accept you know infinitely better about your field than I ever will. So it may only find it’s “niche” in your field, although I suspect it could be more significant than that as future developments come, but it’s already bigger than a niche in general, and growing rapidly. I’m more just surprised about your broad claims outside of your field, which are already demonstrably not correct.